# Convert query letters to uppercase using Management Studio

Tags: ssms

Can I convert query syntax to uppercase using SQL Server Management Studio? I have a bunch of queries that are all written in lowercase letters, and I want to convert them all to uppercase letters. I'm looking for a built-in editor functionality.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Select all of your query. Then go to *Edit > Advanced > Make Uppercase* or simply hit `Ctrl+Shift+U` to make the query uppercase.
Please note that it will make everything uppercase. (i.e., table names, fields name, strings etc.)

**EDIT:**
If you are able to install add-ins, you can also use [SSMS Tools Packs](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com) to uppercase only the keywords.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts (my upvote). You may want to slightly change your note "Please note that ...." to "Please note that if you make the change using Edit > Advanced > Make Uppercase then it will make everything uppercase (i.e., table names, fields name, strings etc.)". But using `Ctrl+Shift+U` will make changes only to the query syntax you selected - and hence, it's a safer option.